# Is there a problem using ARFace with Android and ARCore, because some properties appear to be null always?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore, eye-tracking, ar-foundation

I am working on an Android app that uses eye tracking with Unity. I am using ARFoundation and ARCore. The problem is that when i track a face, and i have the component ARFace, the ARFace.leftEye, ARFace.rightEye and ARFace.fixationPoint are null. I dont know if this is because ARCore does not support this properties of the ARFace and only IOS does because i saw an IOS project that could do this with the ARKit. If anyone knows if its an Android problem or these properties are null for any other reason i would apreciate support.

I've tried to track a face and then track the eyes of the face. I've been able to track the face with ARFaceManager and ARFace but when i try to take the leftEye and rightEye of the ARFace it appears to be null. This shouldn´t happen. Also the fixationPoint is null but the face is tracked correctly and other properties such as the vertices of the ARFace are not null so i guess there has to be some kind of problem with ARCore and Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARCore does not support eye tracking, only ARKit.  Similarly, ARCore does not support blend shapes for the face like ARKit.  All you get with ARCore at this time is a face mesh and tracking of three face regions, the nose tip, and the left and right forehead. See the ARCore documentation at https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arcore@3.0/api/UnityEngine.XR.ARCore.html.